# Как обновить данные в recyclerView в зависимости от выбора пункта spinner?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-spinner

У меня в приложении есть spinner в котором вбит вызов функции для получения данных с сервера. Эти данные отображаються в списке основанном на recyclerView и на адаптере. Так получается что при разных пунктах спиннера мне нужно отображаться разные даннные в списке. Я так понимаю что мне нужно сначала очистить мой arrayList и дальше уведомить об этом мой адаптер. С виду все понятно, и даже получается очистить массив но данные не перерисовываються и я не могу понять почему. Вот нашел способ:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495009/force-recyclerview-to-redraw-android). Но этот способ не работает. Я сделал у себя проверку, если список не пустой при выборе элемента spinner то мы его чистим и потом уже вызываем функцию для заполнения данными. Вот как это выглядит в  спиннере:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        type = 1;
                        ms.setJ_type(type);
                        getL_jobs(offset, type);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        type = 0;
                        ms.setJ_type(type);
                        getL_jobs(offset, type);
                        break;
                    default:
                        type = 1;
                        ms.setJ_type(type);
                        getL_jobs(offset, type);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

и вот функция для получения данных:

```
 public void getL_jobs(final int offset, final int type) {
        if (jobModelArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.w("MY_TAG", "EMPTY");
        } else {
            Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(jobModelArrayList.size()));
            j_adapter = new JobAdapter(jobModelArrayList, getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(j_adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            j_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
...
}
```

До того как нашел приведенный выше способ, пробовал просто чистить список и делать notify adapter, но это не помогло. Не могу понять что я не так сделал.

Comment: Не нужно обнулять адаптер - замените массив с данными и вызовите notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: на что его заменить? на новый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант :

```
public void getL_jobs(final int offset, final int type) {
    if (jobModelArrayList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.w("MY_TAG", "EMPTY");
    } else {
        Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(jobModelArrayList.size()));
        //Нужно реализовать в адаптере получение списка данных
        j_adapter.addData(jobModelArrayList);
        //j_adapter = new JobAdapter(jobModelArrayList, getApplicationContext());
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(j_adapter);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        j_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 ...
 }
```

Я реализовывал сразу метод в классе адаптера:

```
 public void refreshData(List<MyObject> objects){
    mList = objects;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```